# Which is the better with android application, sqlite on client side or memcache on server side, reasons plesae

Tags: java, android, spring, memcached

Which is the better approach, implementing sqlite on client side or implementing memcache on server side? To enhance the performance on android application.

Answer (score 1):

Its depend on the application what you want from it to do. 
**It's obvious to have internet** if you want to fetch anything from server. But if you are fetching from sqlite which is client side **then you don't need internet**.

What you can do is fetch the data from the server once and then if device doesn't have internet connection then just show the client side data from **sqlite** which has been done by so many applications.

What more you can do is you can save data as **json string in a file** and get it which is another approach to get data from client side itself when you have already fetched data from server.

Comment: I have facebook like postes in my application which contains text as well as images in it. Rest service have been implemented on server side, I think saving images and text in sqlite in client side will claim huge space on users disk. which is not a good approach, Thoughts please

Comment: If you want to store the images then what you can do is you can store the image to any **CDN** from where you can get the images whenever you want and **store the url** on client side that way the data would not be saved in huge amount.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on your application requirement.

- If in your application **you want to sync information to server when
  internet connects till then it save in locally on android device**
  then sqlite is good choice. For store in sqlite you don't need
  internet.
- If you want to show the information or details on android device. 
  Lets take an example i have one news application which show current
  news . We cannot store in locally that news because it keep changing
  so use Rest/Soap webservices to retreive data from server. When
  launch that app it call the webservice and retreive current data from
  server.

  For handle webservices requests there is **VOLLEY** option is
  available in android.

  Here is the link for volley implementation :

  http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/
- One thing is you can create a file in your application folder like
  whatsapp do and save information in those file and show to the user.